# illegal start byte 0xf0 in strings.xml

Tags: android, unicode, utf-8

Logcat

```
01-20 20:18:30.608: W/dalvikvm(513): JNI WARNING: illegal start byte 0xf0
01-20 20:18:30.608: W/dalvikvm(513):              string: '??'
01-20 20:18:30.608: W/dalvikvm(513):              in Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;.getArrayStringResource (I)[Ljava/lang/String; (NewStringUTF)
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <string-array name="unicode_array">
      <item>A</item>
   </string-array>
</resources>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a BOM byte that I need to change?

Comment: The byte 0xf0 is not part of DOM. It is invalid as a start byte in UTF-8, as the message says. Can you check with a hex dum what exactly the file contains at byte level?

Answer (score 0):

Simply save the file with plain UTF-8 encoding (as opposed to UTF-8 with BOM) e.g. using a text editor like TextWrangler or SublimeText. That should fix the issue.